# Table and floating

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I have problems with floating header in table. My header should be `colspan="2"` but when I set `float:left` to the td element "header" , colspan stop working. I want something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|Header headher header header                     |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|Something     | Something                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

But I get this:

[image]

My code:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="float: left;">Header header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So don't float... problem solved :)

Comment: But it appears center. How to move it to the left?

Comment: You mean the text inside is centered? Use `style="text-align: left;"` instead of floating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `float:left`, use `text-align:left`.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Header header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UPxQr/)**.